# Which language has more libraries and bindings for Selenium WebDriver? Java or Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3

This question might sound repeated. I have searched Stack exchange and found many questions by users who ask mainly on which language *they* should choose for Selenium WD: ***Java*** or ***Python***?

But their question mainly relates to *ease of use* for the end user: as in which language is easier to learn.

My question is on *capabilities*: Which language has greater capability / more functionality for use with Selenium WebDriver? Java or Python? Are they equal?

I know of some awesome frameworks which use Selenium Bindings with Java such as [Serenity BDD](https://www.thucydides.info/#/) which has awesome reporting capabilities.

Which language is better suited for Selenium WebDriver in terms of capabilities and functionality?

Comment: I marked this question as "Too Broad" because there is no such things as "the best" per se, but only inside a given context. If you explain more your problems and context, the contributors could give their opinions on the different tools.

Comment: This isn't a "too broad" because it's asking which language has more _tooling_ - which can be answered by a combination of how many Selenium features are not supported by Python vs Java, and how many extensions (and what they do) are available in Python vs Java.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official page](https://selenium.dev/downloads/) of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491):

- The core language-specific client drivers are:

  - **Ruby**
  - **JavaScript**
  - **Java**
  - **Python**
  - **C#**

---

However as per [Selenium Official Home Page](https://www.selenium.dev/ecosystem/) language bindings for other languages does exist but those projects are not supported, maintained, hosted, or endorsed by the Selenium project, which are as follows:

- [**Selenium** [Language: Go]](https://github.com/tebeka/selenium)
- [**hs-webdriver** [Language: Haskell]](https://github.com/kallisti-dev/hs-webdriver)
- [**wd** [Language: JavaScript]](https://github.com/admc/wd)
- [**Selenium-Remote-Driver** [Language: Perl]](https://github.com/teodesian/Selenium-Remote-Driver)
- [**php-webdriver** [Language: PHP]](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver)
- [**RSelenium** [Language: R]](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium)
- [**webdriver.dart** [Language: Dart]](https://github.com/google/webdriver.dart)

Now the [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) specific libraries can be installed through the following approaches:

- **Java**: Installation of Selenium libraries for Java can be done using [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717377/getting-selenium-webdriver-example-to-work/47718057#47718057). Add the selenium-java dependency in your project pom.xml:

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **Python**: Installation of Selenium libraries for Python can be done using [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium/48269228#48269228):

  ```
  pip install selenium
  ```

---

Finally, Selenium is not just one tool or API but it composes many tools and all the functionalities are implemented through both the [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) clients and are updated kept updated in sync with the [WebDriver W3C Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/). You can find the complete details in:

- *Java*:

  - [Source Code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium)
  - [Tests](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium)
- *Python*:

  - [Source Code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver)
  - [Tests](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/py/test/selenium/webdriver)

---

### Conclusion

Selenium isn't about the volume of libraries but about how the different clients implements the features optimally as per the **WebDriver W3C Specifications**. Selenium isn't about more libraries but about the *Test Architecture* that best fits into your organizational requirements.